# Couldn't connect to Webspshere MQ from Jboss EAP 7

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

I am using Jboss EAP 7 and IBM MQ 8.0.

When I try to connect to MQ from the Jboss I am getting below issues.

```
15:27:29,872 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inputConnectionFactoryCache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xml/spring-config/spring-config-unit.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EventConnectionFactory1' while setting bean property 'targetConnectionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'it00EventConnectionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] available at JNDI location [EventQueueFactory1] is not assignable to [javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EventQueueFactory1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] available at JNDI location [EventQueueFactory1] is not assignable to [javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] available at JNDI location [it00EventQueueFactory] is not assignable to [javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The JMS connection factories come in sever flavors:

```
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedTopicConnectionFactoryImpl
```

You have:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] available at JNDI location [it00EventQueueFactory] is not assignable to [javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory]
```

You are providing a ConnectionFactory, but the code is expecting a QueueConnectionFactory.

You should change your IBM MQ configuration to provide a:

```
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl
```

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for your reply. I tried changing the code as you mentioned but it did not worked.

Comment: yes the same error. Let me explain you once again. In Standalone-full.xml file I have connection defination like this.<connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/test" enabled="true" connectable="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="test"> and in Spring xm file I created a <bean id="mqConnectionFactory1" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="test"/>
 </bean> and in Jboss-web.xml file I declared resource-ref type as javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

Comment: You are using IBM MQ 8 on EAP 7?  This is not supported.  You must use the IBM MQ 7.5 JCA to talk to IBM MQ 8 from JBoss EAP 7.  JBoss EAP 7.1 supports JMS 2.0 and IBM MQ 8.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. we need to add dependencies in JBoss-deployment-structure.xml file like below.

```
dependencies>
        <module name="javax.jms.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar"/> 
</dependencies>
```